# Keep in memory submitted file until form is valid and clean up

Tags: php, forms, validation, design-patterns

Do you have an elegant solution to validate server side a form containing more than one input type file under these conditions:

- If one file is not valid user will have to upload another
- If one file if valid the server should keep it in memory so user don't have to upload it again.
- Valid file should be shown on the form
- User may just abort and leave the page. Whatever has been saved on the server should be deleted.

As I example let's take a form containing 1 input type text and 2 inputs type file.

```
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

User submit a valid title, a valid file1 but invalid file2.

The goal here is to save each valid file until the form is valid or until session expires or something expires :)

---

Suggestion 1

Generate a unique key for the user form (i.e form123) create a directory /tmp/uploads/form123 where valid file are saved.

A cron running every 10min go through all directories in /tmp/uploads/ and delete the one existing for more than 10min.

With this suggestion the big question is **how to clean up the system if user abandon the form**.

Comment: It's not possible to pre-fill a `file` input, so when the page reloads the user has to select all the files again.

Comment: yes I know, that's why I trying to find a solution to elegantly save a valid file and to not have the user to upload again the file.

Comment: If the file is valid, set a session variable to the location of the temporary file. Then when you display the form, don't display that input if the session variable is set.

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately, I am working with PHP and file are deleted from tmp at the end of php script execution

Comment: Use `move_uploaded_file` to copy them to a different location, then they won't be deleted.

Comment: To clean them up, use a cron job that deletes old temporary files, just like you said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with your suggestion. keep track of valid/invalid entries for the user (you don't even have to save it to disk, just grab the reference and store it in the `$_SESSION` global), and adjust the form based on that.

if the form is invalid, store the submitted, valid files in `$_SESSION`

```
<?php 
    // ... if the form is invalid 
    if (isset($_SESSION['file_1']) { ?>
        <!-- show a placeholder -->
        <!-- i.e. something saying 'file 1' and its name or whatever -->
    <?php } else { ?>
        <!-- show the input -->
    <?php } ?>
```

Then, when the form is finally valid, combine the values you have stored in `$_SESSION` with the information submitted to produce the final, valid form.

Comment: I don't think this can work, files can't be saved in session?